# Redshift of gamma-Ray burst

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy

Can a gamma-ray bursts  be observed at different wave length show different
redshift ?

Answer (score 0):

We measure gamma-ray burst redshifts in the optical or near infrared range. That's where the spectral lines are. We presume, on solid theoretical ground, that the redshifts at longer and shorter wavelengths are the same, but there are no spectral features that can confirm this.

Comment: I would like to know about any research that is conducted to get spectral lines in the gamma range of gamma-ray burst.

Comment: @EdyA. Sounds like a new question.